# How do I access a variable that is outside the scope in a class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Please see the code below:

```
class game{

     constructor(){

       this.a = 'Helloword';
       this.add_event();
      }

     add_event(){

        clicked = function(){

           console.log(this.a); // I want to print hellowowrd

             }        


       let i = document.getElementById('aDiv'); //just a div
       i.addEventListener('click',clicked);

      }}
```

As you can see, inside the clicked function this refers to the div, not the class, but I want to print HelloWorld from '`this.a`', how can I do this.

Comment: can you check about a concept called closures. it might help

Comment: Probably use `bind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve `this` to `self`

```
  add_event() {
    var self = this;
    let i = document.getElementById('aDiv'); 
    i.addEventListener('click', function() { //notice that function given as an argument diretly
      console.log(self.a); // I want to print hellowowrd
    } );
  }
```

**Demo**

```js
class game {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'Helloword';
    this.add_event();
  }

  add_event() {
    var self = this;
    let i = document.getElementById('aDiv'); // just a div
    i.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(self.a); // I want to print hellowowrd
    } );
  }
}
console.log( new game() )
```

```html
<div id="aDiv">aDiv</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using self=this

```
class game{

 constructor(){

   this.a = 'Helloword';
   this.add_event();
  }

 add_event(){
    var self = this
    clicked = function(){

       console.log(self.a); // I want to print hellowowrd

         }        


   let i = document.getElementById('aDiv'); //just a div
   i.addEventListener('click',clicked);

  }}
```

Or I guess you can use the fat arrow syntax

```
clicked (()=>{
       console.log(this.a);
})
```

I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Just let clicked be an arrow function:

```
 add_event(){
    const clicked = () =>{
       console.log(this.a); // It prints hellowowrd
    };
}
```